# In Python, how do you take tokenized input such as with the C++?

Tags: c++, python, input

In *C++*, I can have take input like this:

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

And `a` can be `int`, `b` can be `float`, and `c` can be whatever... How do I do the same in *python*?

`input()` and `raw_input()`, the way I'm using them, don't seem to be giving me the desired results.

Comment: Can you give a better description of what is not "desired" about the results you're getting from raw_input()?  It sounds exactly like what you should want here.

Answer (score 4):

You generally shouldn't use `input()` in production code. If you want an `int` and then a `float`, try this:

```
>>> line = raw_input().split()
>>> a = int(line[0])
>>> b = float(line[1])
>>> c = " ".join(line[2:])
```

It all depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but remember that readability counts. Obscure one-liners may seem cool but in the face of maintainability, try to choose something sensible :)

(P.S.: Don't forget to check for errors with `try: ... except (ValueError, IndexError):`)

Answer (score 3):

Since the C++ cin reads from sys.stdin, you'll often do something more like the following.

```
import sys
tokens= sys.stdin.read().split()
try:
   a= int(token[0])
   b= float(token[1])
except ValueError, e:
   print e # handle the invalid input
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you are doing, something like the [getopt](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-getopt.html) module could be useful, but only in certain situations and I'm not sure if it would apply in yours.